# Display only duplicates values

Tags: laravel

I want to display only books, which have more, than 2 authors. 
I am receiving data from database called books.Pretty much I fighting with syntax, how I should use if statement if, when there are the same values in one column.
When I am using if statement in view file, I am getting error syntax error, unexpected '<' , when only checking if author exist

```
@if({{$book->author}})
    \\view file
     <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Cover</th>
            <th>ISBN</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($books as $book)    
            @if({{$book->author}})
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$book->author}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/book/{{$book->id}}"> {{ $book->name }}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="{{ $book->cover}}" height="42" width="42">
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ $book->isbn}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

Should I change my approach and changed my query in Controller, than books will only include duplicates of authors. If yes, what is the best way to do it

```
public function index()
{
    $books = Book::all();
    return view('books.index', compact('books'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be caused by this snippet of code `@if({{$book->author}})`

the blade function `@if()` opens and closes a php tag itself, but your `{{` `}}` also did this, so compiled it would look like this `<?php if (<?php ... ?>) ?>` which cause this error.

So when using blade functions you don't have to put your php code inside `{{ }}`.
Solve the issue by replacing `@if({{$book->author}})` with `@if($book->author)`

Comment: when I used ``` <?php if($books->author === $books->author){
        echo $books->author;
    };
    ?>```I am receiving error Property [author] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: In your Controller you use `$books = Book::all();` so you get a collection of all books. But the Auther isn't set for this collection. It is set for the book, so you can only get the books auther by `$book->author` like you to in your view by iterating all books. So when you try to get the `auther` property from the whole collection `$books` you receive the error

Comment: what will be yours approach to display book only with authors who has more than 2 books in database

Comment: So you want to display all books with an author who has more than 2 books?

Comment: yes, I think the best way will be the change my query for books variable

Comment: You could try something like this `Book::all()->filter(function ($book) { return $book->author->books->count() > 2; });`

Comment: I have tried you code, but it does not work, I tried ```$books = Book::where('author', '>', 2)->get();
  ``` also not working :-(

Comment: when your model relationships are set correctly mine example should work